# NSIS, set text color on specific words (not the all control)

Tags: winapi, user-interface, colors, nsis

I'm trying to have only specific words in a text area to be a certain color.

```
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0

; Text area
nsDialogs::CreateControl /NOUNLOAD ${__NSD_Text_CLASS} ${DEFAULT_STYLES}|${WS_CLIPCHILDREN}|${WS_TABSTOP}|${ES_WANTRETURN}|${ES_MULTILINE} ${__NSD_Text_EXSTYLE} 5 220 660 115 ''
Pop $1
SendMessage $1 ${EM_SETREADONLY} 1 0
SetCtlColors $1 0x000000 0xFFFFFF ; Black on white

${NSD_SetText} $1 "I want only the 'click me' to be blue ->CLICK ME<-"

nsDialogs::Show
```

How should I do to have only the 'CLICK ME' in blue letters ?

Thanks in advance for any help or hints.

Comment: QA, Please accept answer you found most appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

The thing here is that it is still one single handle (

> HDC

) for all text area.

Take a look at this sample: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162491(v=vs.85).aspx ; the

> TextOut

method...

So, I really doubt that you have any better hasle-free ( including additional plugins ) option than simply use another text control ( split one text control into three text controls ).

Maybe Anders got some trick under the hood... :)

Answer (score 0):

One option is one label on top of the other, the other is using a RichEdit control with RTF content...